# Uncaught TypeError: contenedor_panel.textContent is not a function

Tags: javascript

¿Por qué me aparece ese error? En qué me estoy equivocando:

```
const contenedor_panel = document.createElement("div")
contenedor_panel.textContent("xd")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `textContent` no es una funcion, es una propiedad, necesitas igualar la propiedad con el texto que quieres.  Algo asi:

```js
var contenedor_panel = document.createElement("div")
contenedor_panel.textContent = "xd"
document.body.appendChild(contenedor_panel)
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema era que el valor no se pasaba por paréntesis, sino por el igual.

```
const contenedor_panel = document.createElement("div")
contenedor_panel.textContent = "xd"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]